# How to bind TextBoxes to an XML File (with namespace) 

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, xaml, data-binding

I use C#.
I want to make a Twoways bind between Textboxes and an XML data source. In order to achieve that, I have written this:

```
1  Binding source = new Binding();
2
3  // object ddd = XmlManager.Instance.CreateAttributeOrElement(XPath);
4  source.Path =
5      new PropertyPath(
6          string.Format("(XmlManager.Instance.CreateAttributeOrElement({0}))", XPath));
7  source.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay; 
8
9  UIElementos.UiTexto textoCampo = this as UIElementos.UiTexto;
10 textoCampo.elementoTexto.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, source);
```

Where:

- `XPath = "dummyns/@totalConcept"`
- `XmlManager.Instance.CreateAttributeOrElement` creates the attribute in the XML Document which the bind will to do to TextBoxes.
- The `CreateAttributeOrElement` method of the `XMLManager` object returns some like this:
  `totalConcept=""`

There is a commented line which creates the attribute. The other way is ot make it implicit in the instantiation line of `PropertyPath`. When either of the ways is executed, it generates an XML Document like this:

```
<cna:dummyns xmlns:cna=\"http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd\" totalConcept=\"\" />
```

But when I assign a value to `Textbox`, I get this in the Output window:

```
System.Windows.Data Warning: 78 : BindingExpression (hash=3146959): TransferValue - got raw value {DependencyProperty.UnsetValue}
System.Windows.Data Warning: 86 : BindingExpression (hash=3146959): TransferValue - using fallback/default value ''
System.Windows.Data Warning: 87 : BindingExpression (hash=3146959): TransferValue - using final value ''
```

So the Bind is not working... 
In the line #6, I also tried:

```
string.Format("XmlManager.Instancia.declaracion.Root.Attribute[\"{0}\"].Value", XPath)
```

But I got the same result.

Has anybody got something similar to this working?

Any comments or suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Have you tried using the XPath property instead of the Path property?  From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742451.aspx): "A true XPath expression for binding to an XML data source is not used as a Path value and should instead be used for the mutually exclusive XPath property"

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this ?

```
<XmlDataProvider x:Key="dataProvider" XPath="RootElement" Source="XMLFile1.xml"/>
...

<TextBox Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource dataProvider}, XPath=//ChildElement/@totalConcept }" />
```